# Trying to install Xcode 3.2.6 on a Lion machine but it won't install correctly (Not Date issue)

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, xcode3.2, xcode3to4

So I have some Objective-c code that was created in Xcode 3.1 on OSX 10.5.8, and it will no run in Xcode 4. I used this handy little guide http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110318050811544 on one of my 10.7.4 box and it worked swimmingly. (I had just upgraded from 10.6).

So now I am trying to do the same, install 3.2, install 4, link SDKs etc on another machine running 10.7.3, and after using the little date hack with the same 3.2 mpkg that i used on the other computer, the installer says it finishes successfully but when I go to look, Xcode isn't installed anywhere, and the directory mentioned in the instructions linked above /Developers/SDKs doesn't even exist (it did on the other computer).  I tried copying the 10.5 SDK from the 10.7.4 machine to the 10.7.3 machine and still nothing, 4 won't run it, and I get this error.

> ld: cannot link directly with /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

A little history too,  the 10.7.4 machine had xcode 3 installed on it previous to it's update to lion so that was already there and I didn't have to mess with any of that nonsense. Is it something with having had it installed previous to the Lion upgrade?

So, how do I get Xcode 3 to work on the machine, and second does anyone recognize that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think mean Xcode 4 does run, but can't build your project since that error message is from the linker at the last stage of building your project.

Here's a much easier way to install Xcode 3 on Lion: http://anatomicwax.tumblr.com/post/8064949186/installing-xcode-3-2-6-on-lion-redux

Make sure you install it to a different folder named other than Developer. Xcode 4 may go out of its way to find /Developer and remove it. I named mine /Xcode3.

Comment: I can't up vote you yet otherwise I'd do it multiple times, this solved everything, thanks so much!  Also I had to do this, dunno if everyone did, but you still need set your time back to ~January to get the installation to complete.  Thanks again!